# R equivalent of SAS 'estimate' statement in proc genmod

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to translate some of my coworker's SAS code into R so I can use it in my Rmarkdown report. I am able to fit the same model in R but don't know how to get the `estimate` statement here:

```
proc genmod data= smydata descending;
    class  id_var outcome outcome_name treatment1 treatment2;
    model outcome = outcome_name treatment1*outcome_name treatment2*outcome_name/ type3 dist=bin link=logit  noint covb;
    weight gbm_weights;
    repeated subject=id_var/ type=un corrw;

%let L= 0.1428 0.1428 0.1428 0.1428 0.1428 0.1428 0.1428;
estimate "6.2. H0: avg treatment1 effect =0"  treatment1*outcome_name  &L /e exp alpha = 0.0166;
```

Here `treatment1` and `outcome` are binary. `outcome_name` has 7 levels. The purpose of the test is to see if the average interaction term between `treatment1` and `outcome_name` is nonzero (or different from 1 when exponentiated).

I understand that this is a bit hard to do without the data but I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain in words what the `estimate` statement is supposed to do?

Comment: @BenBolker It tests whether the average of the interaction terms is non-zero. There are 7 levels of `outcome_name` and `treatment1` is binary.

Comment: Add that information into the question itself

Comment: It would also help if you supply the code till the first `run;` statement and if you add the R code you wrote so far.

Comment: @BenBolker the ESTIMATE statement provides a syntax to test H:Lβ=0 where L is the coefficients from EST statement and β is well β

Comment: In general the `multcomp` package (or possibly `emmeans`) will help you compute values and test hypotheses about specific contrasts.  If you just want an overall test of the significance of the interactions you might try fitting the reduced model and calling `anova(full_model, reduced_model)`